# Accessing url internally from Plesk machine

Tags: apache-http-server, plesk

I have a web application that needs to access its own url. E.g., the url is http://staging.foo.com, on that website it calls a resource from http://staging.foo.com/index.php/api/wsdl

However this is failing.

As a test when I login to the command line from my plesk machine and run:

$ curl http://staging.foo.com/ to see if it can access itself, curl returns the Parallels Plesk Panel Default Page.

What do I need to do to make my own url accessible internally?

Thanks

Comment: Plesk panel v: 11.0.9 Update #60 on CentOS 6.4